# Iterate over values in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matrix, dataframe

i have a matrix in pandas

```
print reducedMatrix
       0      1     3      4
    1  2  99991     0      0
    2  0      4     0      1
    3  3      0  9991      2
    4  1      0     2  99989
```

and want to iterate over it and print i and j for zero values, I use:

```
for i,rows in reducedMatrix.iterrows():
        for j,cols in reducedMatrix.iteritems():
            if (reducedMatrix[i][j] == 0): #here we check all zero values
                print i,j
```

but it does not work

the expected  output

```
1,3
1,4
2,0
2,3
3,0
4,1
```

It's essential to save row and col names

how do I achieve that?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using numpy's `where` function.

```
np.where(df.values == 0)
```

will return the indices of rows and columns that match the condition. In order to retrieve the original row and column names:

```
rows, cols = np.where(df.values == 0)
list(zip(df.index[rows], df.columns[cols]))
```